# Pivot spark dataframe with total

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
|id|year|
|--|----|
|a |2015|
|a |2016|
|a |2017|
|b |2015|
|b |2017|
```

I can pivot it to get:

```
|id|2015|2016|2017|
|--|----|----|----|
|a |  1 |  1 |  1 |
|b |  1 |  0 |  1 |
```

using:

```
val result = data.groupBy("id").pivot("year").count().na.fill(0)
```

I want to add a total column (The sum of all years). What is the most efficient way of getting this?

```
|id|2015|2016|2017|Total|
|--|----|----|----|-----|
|a |  1 |  1 |  1 |   3 |
|b |  1 |  0 |  1 |   2 |
```

I currently take the above result and sum the years columns.

```
val columnsToSum = result.columns.filterNot(c=> Seq("id").contains(c))
result.withColumn("Total", columnsToSum.map(col(_)).reduce(_ + _))
```

Is there a better way to do this (a built in function)?

Comment: You have the best solution I guess. :)